# Beep sound in headphone

Tags: sound

Every time I use headphones, when the PulseAudio process switches from Sleeping to Running state and from Running to Sleeping, I hear a beep sound. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thank you.

My laptop model : Acer Swift 3 SF314-511, and Ubuntu Version : 23.04

Comment: Please edit and post more details about laptop model and ubuntu version.